# Does Whatsapp require verification after Factory Reset?

Tags: samsung, whatsapp-messenger, factory-reset, samsung-galaxy-s7

I recently had a problem with my Samsung S7 edge. It keeps on restarting and after removing cache, it still restarts after a few minutes. I found out that the most effective way to fix it is a factory reset. The problem is that, I am overseas and I could not receive any calls or text. Hence, I would not be able to verify my Whatsapp number.

Does anyone know whether Whatsapp requires verification after factory reset or does anyone know how to fix the problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes it does. You'll need to input the code sent to your phone number

Comment: An alternative way would be to ask someone to forward the code to you if  you left your SIM card home.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it will require verification, and you will need to be able to receive a text to verify your number with WhatsApp.  If your device/carrier has the ability to send/receive texts over wifi, that may be an option for you to verify your number.

Per WhatsApp's FAQ Page [here](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/20970873/?category=5245245):

> *Requirements*
>
> - You can only verify a phone number you own.
> - You must be able to receive phone calls and SMS to the phone number you are  trying to verify.
> - You must have any call-blocking settings, apps or task killers disabled.
> - You must have a working Internet connection through mobile data or Wi-Fi. If you are roaming or have a bad connection, verification may
>     not work. Try opening www.whatsapp.com on your phone’s Internet
>     browser to see if you are connected to the Internet.
>
> *If you didn't receive the 6-digit code by SMS*
>
> - If the timer runs out before you receive the code, an option will appear to request a phone call. Choose the Call me option to request
>     the call. When you answer the call, an automated voice should tell you
>     the 6-digit code. Insert that to verify WhatsApp.